# What's a good way to validate access to models in controller specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, tdd, rspec-rails

I have `Users` which create `HomeRepairTickets`.

`Firms` can create `TicketBid`s for `HomeRepairTicket`s they are interested in.

Should my controller spec ensure that `Firm`s can only bid on `HomeRepairTicket`s they have access to? And make sure they can only `update` `HomeRepairTicket`s that they created?

Or is there a better way to test appropriate authentication (eg that the ids match or that the authentication_token matches)

I'm using `rspec`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use externalized authorization / attribute-based access control ([abac](/questions/tagged/abac)).

ABAC is an authorization model defined by NIST that lets you describe authorization requirements in terms of attributes and policies. Based on your question, you would want to implement a policy along the lines of

```
A user can view a ticket if the ticket belongs to the same firm as the user.
```

With ABAC you can have as many policies as you like. There is a standard called XACML that implements ABAC but I do not believe there is anything in Ruby that implements XACML.

Your best bet is the CanCanCan gem which provides you with similar capabilities. Check it out [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/cancancan/versions/1.13.1).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is 'yes'.

"Firms can only bid on HomeRepairTickets they have access to" and "Firms can only update HomeRepairTickets that they created" are good functional requirements (aka system behaviors). You should definitely be testing at this level.

Now, you may decide to test at lower levels (e.g., tokens/ids matching, etc.) as you go along developing, but it's always good to come back to testing your high-level requirements and make sure your system is well-behaved.

Whether or not your authentication lives in a controller is a whole other topic. As is how you choose to represent your authentication logic. But, it's all good stuff.